# i have problem in uploading files to specific folder it is permession not enough

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having aproblem uploading files to a specific folder on my web server. How can I give permession to this folder and what is the vital user in that case ?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give write permission to the folder to asp.net user, but you need to give more details like how are you testing your app IIS  or VS build in server for you to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what identity your application pool is running as.

Seeing you haven't mentioned which version of IIS your using, I'll assume IIS7 :-)

Right click on the application pool and select "Advanced Settings..." and take a look at the identity of the pool. Make sure this identity has the correct file system permissions.